# C++ SFML collision is not accurate

Tags: c++, collision, sfml

I'm making a 2D game with SFML in C++ and I have a problem with collision. I have a player and a map made of tiles. Thing that doesn't work is that my collision detection is not accurate. When I move player up and then down towards tiles, it ends up differently.

[image: Player very high above tile]
[image: Player above tile]
[image: Player standing on tile]

I am aware that source of this problem may be calculating player movement with use of delta time between frames - so it is not constant. But it smooths movement, so I don't know how to do it other way. I tried with constant speed valuses and to make collision fully accurate - speed had to be very low and I am not satisfied with that.

```
void Player::move() {
    sf::Vector2f offsetVec;

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
        offsetVec += sf::Vector2f(0, -10);

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S))
        offsetVec += sf::Vector2f(0, 10);

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
        offsetVec += sf::Vector2f(-10, 0);

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D))
        offsetVec += sf::Vector2f(10, 0);

    this->moveVec += offsetVec;
}

void Player::update(float dt, Map *map) {
    sf::Vector2f offset = sf::Vector2f(this->moveVec.x * this->playerSpeed * dt,
                                       this->moveVec.y * this->playerSpeed * dt);
    sf::Sprite futurePos = this->sprite;
    futurePos.move(offset);
    if (map->isCollideable(this->pos.x, this->pos.y, futurePos.getGlobalBounds())) {
        this->moveVec = sf::Vector2f(0, 0);
        return;
    }
    this->sprite.move(offset);
    this->pos += offset;
    this->moveVec = sf::Vector2f(0, 0);
    return;
}
```

In **player position update** I create future sprite object, which is object after applying movement, to get it's boundaries and pass it to collision checker. To **collision checker** I also pass player pos, because my map is stored in 2d array of tile pointers, so I check only these in player range.

```
bool Map::isCollideable(float x, float y, const sf::FloatRect &playerBounds) {
    int startX = int(x) / Storage::tileSize;
    int startY = int(y) / Storage::tileSize;
    Tile *tile;
    for (int i = startX - 10; i <= startX + 10; ++i) {
        for (int j = startY - 10; j <= startY + 10; ++j) {
            if (i >= 0 && j >= 0) {
                tile = getTile(i, j);
                if (tile != nullptr && playerBounds.intersects(tile->getGlobalBounds()))
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

[Full project on Github](https://github.com/Viters/Watch)

#### My solution

I have changed if statement in update function to while statement, which decreases my offset vector till no collision is present. I still have to make some adjustments, but general idea is:

```
void Player::update(float dt, Map *map) {
    int repeats = 0;
    sf::Vector2f offset = sf::Vector2f(this->moveVec.x * this->playerSpeed * dt,
                                       this->moveVec.y * this->playerSpeed * dt);
    sf::Sprite futurePos = this->sprite;
    while (map->isCollideable(this->pos.x, this->pos.y, futurePos, offset)) {
        offset = 0.7f * offset;
        repeats++;
        if (repeats > 5) {
            this->moveVec = sf::Vector2f(0, 0);
            return;
        }
    }
    this->sprite.move(offset);
    this->pos += offset;
    this->moveVec = sf::Vector2f(0, 0);
    return;
}
```

I also had to rework isCollideable method a little, so it accepts sf::Sprite and offset vector so it can calculate boundaries on it's own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the player collides with a tile, you should calculate the penetration, that is, the value of "how much the player went into the tile". When you have this value, nudge your player back that much.

Comment: I actually did it otherwise, but thanks to your idea. I didn't come up with how to get smfl penetration values (it would be complicated because I would need to check every side exclusively). Although I made some operations on offset vector knowing, that previous one is going to make collision.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a thought but you could have some inaccuracies in your collision detection  when you typecast the float x, and y to integers and then divide them. This could cause problems because some of the data in the float could be lost. If the float was 3.5 or 3.3 or 3.9 then it would become 3 which throws off your collision calculations.

Comment: I only typecast x, y floats to int to calculate which tiles around player should I check. Collision calculations are made using float values.

Comment: you could be checking the wrong tile though because of that though